# Validating user input in GSheets / Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logic

I have data that looks like the following:

```
Task   |   Number
A      |     1
B      |     2
C      |     2
D      |     3
E      |     3
F      |     3
```

There are two columns. One with tasks and the other with values. My goal is on Google Sheets, when the user enters in a task and a number, that the code will check against all the other numbers

So for instance, if I have the above data, and the user enters again

F   |    3

that the code will reject this user input

Below is the code. I have run it, and in the alert boxes, the equation

```
 ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() == ss.getRange(rng.getRow(), rng.getColumn()).getValue()
```

uniformly validates to false. So the following code will declare 3 == 3 is actually a false statement. The question is why? And, how can I correct this problem?

```
 function checkEntry(){

  //store the range as that cell
  var rng = ss.getRange(8, 2)

  //ui.alert(rng.getValue());
  var dict = {}
  var i = 2
  var k = 1

  //check the sheet
  for(i=2;i<=last;i++){
    ui.alert(ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue());
    ui.alert(ss.getRange(rng.getRow(), rng.getColumn()).getValue());

    ui.alert(ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue() == ss.getRange(rng.getRow(), rng.getColumn()).getValue());


  }
```

Comment: The code doesn't run at all because "last" is undefined. See [mcve] . Also, (8, 2) is in the 8th row, which your sample data does not have. Finally, if your code has a bunch of getRange().getValue() in a loop, you are using Apps Script wrong.  There should be one call to `getRange`, before the loop; the range being all the data you want to access in this function.

Answer (score 0):

I  think this will work for you.

```
function checkEntry(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rng.getValues();
  var u=[];//uniques
  var r=[];//duplicates
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    var s=vA[i][0].toString()+vA[i][1].toString();
    if(u.indexOf(s)==-1){
      u.push(s);
    }else{
      r.push(i);
    }
  }
  for(var i=vA.length-1;i>0;i--){
    if(r.indexOf(i)>-1){
      sh.deleteRow(i+1);//delete duplicates
    }
  }
}
```